# Error when importing secret key from .env

Tags: solana-program, keypair, solana-keygen

I am working through
https://www.soldev.app/course/intro-to-cryptography

and at the point where I am attempting to import the secret key from a .env

I am getting an error:

[image]

My keypair is set using:

import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const keypair = Keypair.generate();

console.log(`The public key is:` , keypair.publicKey.toBase58());
console.log(`The secret key is:` , keypair.secretKey);
console.log(`✅ Finished!`);

not sure how to resolve it as I am already using a base58.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is expecting you to have a keypair in your .env file.

You can just create that file next to your ts files and add the key

```
SECRET_KEY=[yourkeypair]
```

You can generate a new one like so:

```
solana-keygen grind --starts-with dev:1
```

and then copy the contents into your .env file

Then you can also get the address

```
solana address keypair.json
```

and then airdrop some sol to it for example:

```
solana airdrop -k keypair.json
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply.
I do have the key in my .env file 
it is in the same directory as the ts file 
in this format:
SECRET_KEY="[(a series of numbers)]"

Comment: GOT IT! lol it was a syntax error.. I had [(numbers)]
needed to remove ()